# Confusion with Angular component property binding

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using the PrimeNG UI components on an Angular 5 application and I have a little confusion about they way to bind values to some of their properties. I'll explain it with an example:

According to the documentation (https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion), these are the properties for AccordionTab:

```
Name       Type     Default   Description
header     string   null      Title of the tab.
selected   boolean  false     Defines if the tab is active.
disabled   boolean  false     Defines whether the tab can be selected
```

And then, in the code, we have the following example:

```
<p-accordion>
  <p-accordionTab header="Header 1" [selected]="true">
    Content 1
  </p-accordionTab>
  <p-accordionTab header="Header 2">
    Content 2
  </p-accordionTab>
  <p-accordionTab header="Header 3">
    Content 3    
  </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

As you can see, **header** is used without brackets, while **selected** does use them. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but brackets are used to bind values to the component properties, while a literal without brackets refers to a directive, right?

Why are they used differently in this case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `[]` that means it contains a expression. This is for object binding to properties `(@Input()` of an Angular component or directive or a property of a DOM element

Here `[selected]="true"` will get the value `true` and not `"true"`. That means you can also pass array, variables ... here and other complex expressions as well.

The thing you have in `header` is always a string value.

More details can be found here https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Comment: or if he wants to he can pass [header]="foo", where foo is a variable stored in the component.

Comment: @BoantaIonut yes exactly.

Comment: thats explained in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Using the property name on its own reads whatever is in the quotes literally. `header="Title Name"` will pass `"Title Name"` into the header property.

Using `[]` around a propertyname allows you to reference a variable or function. `[header]="TitleName"` with `TitleName() {return "Title Name"}` or `TitleName = "Title Name"` in your class within the component file